# Cual es el motivo de que una vez importadas las clases completas con asterisco, se importan nuevamente sub-clases de la misma en Java Swing?

Tags: java, java-swing

es algo que me cuestiono desde que comencé a estudiar programación, que le he preguntado incluso a dos profesores, y que uno sin contestar me cambió de tema porque según dijo no era el momento de explicarlo, y la otra me dijo que era por cuestiones de agilizar el acceso, pero no me queda muy claro

Alguien sabe el motivo de porqué, una vez importada una clase completa, ejemplo:

```
import java.util.*;
```

En el mismo programa, nos encontramos con las siguientes importaciones adicionales ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Cuando empecé mis estudios, me explicaron que con el asterisco se importa toda la clase y sub-clases, sin embargo es habitual encontrarse con importaciones totales y parciales

Alguien me lo puede explicar ?

Porque buscando por internet he visto poca información al respecto y muy ambigua

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Según tengo entendido es mala práctica importar la librería completa porque es ineficiente, ya que son más de 50 clases que estaríamos importando

Comment: Entiendo @Joshin, o sea, que incluso usar el asterisco estaría desaconsejado. Pues lo tendré en cuenta. Muchas gracias. Lo que no comprendo entonces, es porque no lo aconsejan así los profesores, al menos en mi caso.

Comment: En mi caso, el docente nos aconsejo no usar el asterisco; supongo yo porque al no indicarle al programa que librería específico usar se tiene que hacer una búsqueda de las tantas clases que tiene, bueno es mi humilde opinión no soy un experto recién estoy en aprendizaje

Comment: En los 90's no habían IDEs tan poderosas como ahora, que importan automáticamente. Y las clases en los paquetes no eran tantas, entonces a menos que te aprendieras todas las clases de un paquete y regresaras constantemente al inicio del archivo con un editor de texto arcaico, era más cómodo simplemente importar todo el paquete.

Comment: Es mala práctica pero no porque sea ineficiente sino porque puede causar colición de nombres. Las líneas adicionales que muestras no son necesarias pero tampoco hace ningún mal que esten ahí. Como desarrollador no deberías preocuparte por eso, simplemente deja que se encargue tu IDE. No mencionaste cual estás usando pero debería permitirte desactivar esos wildcard imports. Aunque en general no deberían causarte ningún problema.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Correcto, no es ineficiente ya que no hace import de todas las clases. Sin embargo, él tiene puestos imports que sí necesita que estén, los de regex. Solo son innecesarios los de ArrayList y Scanner, pero como bien dijiste, no molestan.

Comment: Hola @SinneroftheSystem y MTM, los import que muestro, los he tomado de un ejercicio de los apuntes de la asignatura de Desarrollo de Interface del ciclo DAM para un programa en Java Swing con el interface de Netbeans. Y me ha llamado la atención que en esos mismo apuntes comenten que con el asterisco se importe toda la clase, y luego ellos mismos además de la clase total con el asterisco, importen paquetes adicionales de la misma clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los imports, cuando escribes un asterisco, te dará acceso a los imports que están después del paquete de util, pero no al siguiente, es decir:

```
import java.util.*;
```

Este import te dará acceso a todo lo que esta después de util, como por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Sin embargo, no te dará acceso a estos otros, por estar un paquete más allá de util:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Como curiosidad, cuando haces import con asterisco, **en realidad no hace import de todos**, simplemente te hará import del que necesites en el programa. Es decir, es dinámico, no te va a ir más lento ni ocupará más espacio por poner *, solo llamará a los que necesites cuando en el código los llames.

Entonces, ¿por qué a veces se pone el import exacto en vez de usar siempre asteriscos?

La única razón es que así puedes ver claramente qué imports has necesitado concretamente, por lo que cuando trabajes en empresas, lo más correcto sería utilizar imports completos, para que los demás vean qué importas exactamente.

Espero haberte ayudado.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Vaya @MTM, pues sinceramente, ahora si que me ha quedado claro, o sea, que el importar los paquetes del general, de padre por decirlo de alguna forma, no importa los sub paquetes de sus hijos. Pues muchas gracias

Comment: Muy importante destacar que el asterisco no implica ineficiencia, cosa que afirmaban por arriba... Me alegro que te haya quedado claro (: